# Sql Table in Windows Phone 8

Tags: sql, windows-phone-8

Is the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202876(v=vs.105).aspx
demonstrating sql table? Can we perform sql queries in this table?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the article carefully, you'll find following link: [**Local database for Windows Phone**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). In the first paragraph it states:

> Windows Phone apps use LINQ to SQL for all database operations; LINQ to SQL is used to define the database schema, select data, and save changes to the underlying database file residing in the local folder.

### Note (further down the page):

**LINQ to SQL on Windows Phone does not directly support executing Transact-SQL, including Data Definition Language (DDL) or Data Modeling Language (DML) statements.** Additionally, Windows Phone apps cannot use LINQ to SQL to directly access ADO.NET objects. For more information, see **[LINQ to SQL support for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202872%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)**.